# Perl DB2 update sql issue

Tags: sql, perl, db2

I am facing an issue while updating into DB2 using Perl.

Even though the data exist in the table update query is throwing below error:
SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000

Below is the code:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE <table> SET <column1> = ?, <column2> = ? WHERE <column3> = ? AND <column4> = ?");

#  start new transaction #
$dbh->begin_work();

foreach my $row (@status_ary)
{
    $sth->execute(@$row);

    if ( $sth->errstr )
    {
         print $sth->errstr, "\n";
    }
}
$dbh->commit();
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

I am also performing inserting of data into this table way before and there is no issue in that but when it comes to update i am getting now row exist error even though row exist for the specified where clause. 
I also checked the values being passed for place holders and are fine.

I also enabled DBI trace and below is the part of log:

```
<- connect= DBI::db=HASH(0x2cc9e70)
    <- STORE('dbi_connect_closure', CODE(0x2d571b8))= 1 at DBI.pm line 755
    <- prepare('UPDATE <table> SET <column1> = ?, <column2> = ? WHERE <column3> = ? AND <column4> = ?')= DBI::st=HASH(0x30189c8) at library.pm line 308
    <- DESTROY(DBI::st=HASH(0x2d8ca28))= undef at library.pm line 311
    <- begin_work= 1 at library.pm line 311
    !! info: '' '[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000
' (err#0)
<- execute(1, '760.38', ...)= '0E0' at library.pm line 322
       info: '' '[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000
' (err#0)
```

Comment: I really don't know Perl or DB2, but I can suggest that you print out the raw query which your Perl code is executing.  Then try running that directly on DB2 and see if you get errors.

Comment: Hi tim, i searched for ways to do so but couldn't find a way in perl to print the update statement with placeholders populated with values. We can just print the statement and also the values what we are trying to bind. But couldn't find any way to print the query will values.

Comment: I suspect that your `WHERE` clause is not matching any records.  Where do you bind the parameters?  I see this nowhere in your code.

Comment: In execute statement i am sending binding values.$sth->execute(@$row);

Comment: Check the binding values and make sure you have matching records.  Any chance the prepared statement needs to be told what types that placeholder values are?

Comment: s i believe there is some problem in binding. As i have placed a trigger in DB2 on update of this table and writting the update data into new table. But the trigger is not invoked which means update query was not fired on the table or there was some issue with update query.

Comment: My guess is that it is the query, in particular the way you are binding values.

Comment: Perl experts pls help me in resolving this issue. I also updated question with  part of DBI trace logs for the update.

Comment: It is impossible to justify from you code snippet, but for DB2 you have to execute `SET CURRENT SCHEMA XXX` before some other query

Comment: In the above update query <table> = <schema>.<tablename> and the above table exist under default schema. I think the problem is with binding because if i give some dummy values directly into the update statement it works but with binding not working. In binding the first one is integer field and remaining 3 are varchar fields at DB2 and also the binding variables are maintained in same way. Pls guide me if i am wrong.

Comment: The error means that the `where` clause didn't match any rows.  The most likely cause is that `@$row` does not contain the data you expect it to.  I would use the debugger or some other method to inspect this.

Comment: Thanks Guys. The problem was with the data in the array. I dont know from where but a dot was getting added for two values which was causing problem while forming update statement. Resolved it using chop and now its working fine.